# Docker on Elastic Beanstalk => Run terminal with environment configuration

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Running EBS with Single Docker Container. I have used the environment variables configuration of EBS to set things like connection strings, etc.

I'd like to connect to a machine and run a terminal in a new container.

That's easy enough, I would just need to:

```
eb ssh
```

and then

```
sudo docker run -it my-image bash
```

However, I want that terminal environment to have the same configuration as the application (think of heroku run).

It looks like the environment is assembled for the actual application run in /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/00run.sh, but I haven't had any luck adapting it to my purposes.

Is there an approved way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is closely related to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572970/how-to-run-rails-migrations-and-seeding-in-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-single-conta/31932687#31932687_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572970/how-to-run-rails-migrations-and-seeding-in-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-single-conta/31932687#31932687) and I am using @nmott 's answer for this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

. /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/common.sh

EB_SUPPORT_FILES=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k support_files_dir)

EB_CONFIG_DOCKER_ENV_ARGS=()

while read -r ENV_VAR; do
  EB_CONFIG_DOCKER_ENV_ARGS+=(--env "$ENV_VAR")
done < <($EB_SUPPORT_FILES/generate_env)

docker run --rm "${EB_CONFIG_DOCKER_ENV_ARGS[@]}" -it <image> bash
```

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this:

```
container_commands:
  rake_db_migrate:
    command: docker run --rm --env-file /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env.list REGISTRY_ADDR/backend:GITHUB_SHA_SHORT rake db:migrate
    leader_only: true
    ignoreErrors: false
```